# calling geolocation service with async API Call

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS with geolocation service using Yelp API. I am able to call the service in my controller and pass the location to the service. But when I redirect to the results page I am getting a blank screen because of the async nature of $http.JSONP call. Any suggestions how I should be wiring this?

```
$geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function(position) {
        var ll = position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude;
        $scope.myPosition = position
        return ll;

     }).then(function(data){
        console.log('ll:'+data);
        var ll=data;
        var type=YelpService.getTerm();
        var zipcode='xxxxx';
        var sortBy='distance';
        var searchRadius='10';
        console.log('type:'+type);
        YelpService.retrieveYelpResults(type,$http,ll,zipcode,sortBy,searchRadius,$q,function(data){
            console.log('after retrieving getResults');   
            $scope.businesses = data.businesses;
            console.log('result length:'+$scope.businesses.length);

      });
     })
```

Comment: can you try setTimeout()?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use resolve provided by ui-router. Got it working now...Thanks